# Running PyPDFOCR on Windows via Python - Requiring Poppler?

Tags: windows, python-2.7, poppler

I'm working on a project that requires the conversion of PDFs into their searchable counterparts, and have found that PyPDFOCR does exactly what I need to get the job done. However, when trying to install the module and its external dependencies, I'm running into issues where I can't download anything windows-related that defines `pdfimages` such as Poppler. I've search all around for any ways to install Poppler in order to run the module, but nothing seems to be supported or working. Any ideas?

Comment: I noticed a lot of people are having similar issues, so I wrote a short article on how to resolve Poppler on Windows.  It's not appropriate for an answer, but will help you nonetheless. Here's the article: https://medium.com/@matthew_earl_miller/poppler-on-windows-179af0e50150

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the Poppler download from:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/poppler-win32/ for Windows platform

https://poppler.freedesktop.org/ for Linux platform